# Does let replace anonymous closures for having private variables?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

If you want to have some kind of private variables in JavaScript you could place the code in an anonymous closure, right? Now since `let` was included, is this specific use case of a closure gone? Or is it still relevant?

Example in top level:

```
// global variable a
var a = 6;

// using let
{
  // new variable a that only lives inside this block
  let a = 5;
  console.log(a); // => 5
}

console.log(a); // => 6

// using a closure
(function() {
  // again a new variable a that only lives in this closure
  var a = 3;
  console.log(a); // => 3
})();

console.log(a); // => 6
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Since I have very few experience developing in JavaScript I wanted to know if using a closure for this use case is still the right choice, or if it's better to use `let` (apparently using let everywhere you can is the way to go - at least instead of var. That's what I learned from reading all the fancy blog posts about let.)

Comment: those closure are called [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) and before ES6 2015 they were the only way to go if we were to use private variables without polluting the global scope. Now since `const` and `let` have arrived you should use them because they give [block scope](https://edgecoders.com/function-scopes-and-block-scopes-in-javascript-25bbd7f293d7?gi=26a2ac2feb07). But for code which stills needs to execute inline we use an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript).

Comment: What do you mean with `code which stills needs to execute inline`? I understand that code inside an IIFE will be executed immediately, but won't be code inside a block will be executed immediately, too?

Comment: say if you wanted to make an AJAX call to the server to get some data from the database on the page load or some pre-initialization regardless of any condition, in those cases you'd still need an IIFE to accomplish that

Comment: So I would make the request and use an IIFE as the callback? Maybe you want to formulate your comments as an answer since you actually answered my question (and maybe provide a code snippet which underlines your example? That would be great as I didn't find that specific example in a quick google session).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something called [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#Technical_example) in Javascript, which "hoists" the variable above even before initialization.

```
// global variable a
var a = 6;

// using let
{
  // new variable a that only lives inside this block
  let a = 5;
  console.log(a); // => 5
}

console.log(a); // => 6

// using a closure
(function() {
  // again a new variable a that only lives in this closure
  var a = 3;
  console.log(a); // => 3
})();

console.log(a); // => 6
```

So this code changes to:

```
// The global variable 'a' is hoisted on the top of current scope which is Window as of now
var a;

// Initialization takes place as usual
a = 6;


// This is a block
{

  // This local variable 'a' is hoisted on the top of the current scope which is the 'block'
  let a;

  a = 5;
  console.log(a); // => 5
}

console.log(a); // => 6

// Using an IIFE
(function() {

  // This local variable 'a' is hoisted on the top of the current scope which is the block of IIFE
  var a;

  a = 3;
  console.log(a); // => 3
})();

console.log(a); // => 6
```

Pre ES6 we used to use [IIFEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) to make variables which would not pollute the global scope, but after ES6 we generally use `let` and `const` because they provide [block-scope](https://edgecoders.com/function-scopes-and-block-scopes-in-javascript-25bbd7f293d7?gi=26a2ac2feb07).